# NiFi StandardFlowFileRecord is not known in this session

Tags: apache-nifi

I am evaluating NiFi and have created a basic workflow, It listens a local directory, apply some transformations and then put the flow in kafka, But while putting message in kafka I am getting below error.

Error trace

```
09:46:35 UTC ERROR1b6ae25f-e517-47d9-90a2-103109a47b90  localhost:10084

PutKafka[id=1b6ae25f-e517-47d9-90a2-103109a47b90] Failed to process session due to org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.FlowFileHandlingException: 
StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=746f505e-54ec-4b9f-a970-1f88cda08a2e,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1455788674669-223, container=default, section=223], offset=0, length=131876],offset=0,name=1_edr_http_EAST.COMPLETED.9,size=131876] is not known in this session (StandardProcessSession[id=134420]): 
org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.FlowFileHandlingException: StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=746f505e-54ec-4b9f-a970-1f88cda08a2e,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1455788674669-223, container=default, section=223], offset=0, length=131876],offset=0,name=1_edr_http_EAST.COMPLETED.9,size=131876] is not known in this session (StandardProcessSession[id=134420])
```

My workflow looks like
[image]

BasicFieldSplitProcessor is my custom processor, it is modified version of ReplaceText.

Config of "Field Split out queue"

- FlowFile expiration  Info:120 sec
- Back pressure object threshold 
  Info:500000
- Back pressure data size threshold  Info:200 MB

Comment: Can you share information on the version of Apache NiFi you are running?

Comment: I am using nifi-0.4.1, compiled with hadoop-2.4.0

Comment: Ok thanks.  And can you share what properties you have set on PutKafka.  Definitely want to get to the bottom of this asap.

Comment: my flow template https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/28965206/share/basic_field_split.xml

Comment: thank you - will take a look and let you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok thanks for all the help getting the details.  We've been able to replicate and a member of the community is working on solving it now.  For now we believe you can simply set run duration to 0 seconds and see better behavior.  Please confirm.   https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-1534